# Flash in zBar Camera

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, zbar

I am using ZBAR for Qr code scanning. I had implemented ZBar correctly. Now I want to make flash light on or off in Zbar.

On ZBar website I only get information about Torch but no information about flash light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "flash" is when the light "flashes" for a split second. The "torch" is when the light stays on. You do want "torch", not "flash". It would be hard to scan a barcode if the light only flashed for a split second.

I've done what you are look for. I added a `UIBarButtonItem` to the navbar. I created the button with a custom image. The button handler is as follows:

```
- (void)torchToggle:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    if (button.style == UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered) {
        self.readerView.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOff;
        if (self.readerView.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
            button.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
        }
    } else {
        self.readerView.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
        if (self.readerView.torchMode != AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
            button.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but i need this functionality in my app. Is it possible?

Comment: If i use this it will only open Torch not Flash LIght

Comment: The purpose of this code is to act like a flashlight (or a torch as they say in the UK). In iOS there is no "flash light". There is "flash" or "torch". "torch" is the same as a "flashlight".

Comment: I am getting error like : "Use undeclared variable AVCaptureTorchModeOff"

Comment: Add the following import: `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You can on or off flash simply with below code

```
ZBarReader?.cameraFlashMode = .off
```