# How to set camera flash light level in zbar sdk

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk

I am using zbar sdk in my ios app. I want to dim the camera flash light.
In ios documentation I have found [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/setTorchModeOnWithLevel%3aerror%3a)

```
- (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError
```

In AVCaptureDevice class setTorchModeOnWithLevel function sets the light level between 0-1.
In zbar sdk I have found this object in readerview class
I am using following code

```
    ZBarReaderViewController *mReader =  [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
    mReader.showsZBarControls = NO;
    mReader.showsHelpOnFail = NO;
    mReader.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;

    mReader.readerDelegate = self;
    //    reader.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    mReader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraView.frame.size.width , cameraView.frame.size.height);

    mReader.view.frame = cropRect;

    mReader.cameraOverlayView = [self setOverlayPickerView];
    AVCaptureDevice *mDevice = mReader.readerView.device; //mReader.readerView.device returns object of AVCaptureDevice
```

When I try to access AVCaptureDevice functions it show nothing in suggestion and when I write it manually then it give error.

```
[mDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5 error:error];
```

How I can use AVCaptureDevice object so that I can set the dim level of flash light??

Comment: please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263296/flash-in-zbar-camera

Comment: I want to dim the light of camera flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling following function which  give error

```
[mDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5 error:error];
```

The reason of error was that I have not included AVFoundation library in build setting. After including my error resolves
[@rakeshNS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818514/rakeshns) we can dim the zbar sdk light by using

```
AVCaptureDevice *mDevice = mReader.readerView.device;
[mDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5 error:nil];
```

Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Zbar SDK to control Flash light level. You just can Turn On/Turn Off the flash.

Answer (score -1):

I am using below code hope it can help you :)

```
reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

reader.readerView.torchMode = 2;
reader.showsZBarControls = FALSE;
reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
[reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_ISBN13
                      config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                          to: 0];
reader.readerView.zoom = 1.0;

reader.cameraOverlayView = [self setLayoutView];


if([[defaults valueForKey:@"flashLight1"] isEqualToString:@"off"] )
    reader.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
else
reader.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
```

Comment: I want to dim the light of camera flash.