# How to turn off the flash light while scanning using ipod

Tags: ios, camera, ipod, zbar, flashlight

I am using an iPod to scan tickets, But whenever i scan the ticket the flash light flashes. If I turn off the flash light in the camera, It is working fine(Does not flash).Is there any other way to do this other than turning off the flash light of the camera manually?? I am using Zbar library. I am using xamarin to develop the app.

Comment: You should research `Zbar`. It's a very little library and it's easy to turn off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like,

```
 AVCaptureDevice *mDevice = mReader.readerView.device;
 [mDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5 error:nil];  // you can use different torchmode!
```

or

```
 [myDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff]; // off torchmode
```

Dopn't forget to import `AVFoundation`.

You can refer [this answewr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711867/how-to-set-camera-flash-light-level-in-zbar-sdk) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263296/flash-in-zbar-camera) for more details.

Hope this will help :)